# Excel Date Picker Date format

Tags: excel, datepicker, vba

I am experiencing an issue where the date picker in excel appears to be using the US version of a date that i am searching for.

I am trying to check if a work sheet exists where in a range of cells a date exists that fall in the parameters of DTpicker1 and DTpicker2.

Can anyone advise how i can force the code to check the date in a uk format?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim s As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
UserForm1.Hide
For Each s In Worksheets
    If CBool(Application.CountIfs(s.Range("E11:E37"), ">" & 
    Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/mm/yy"), _ s.Range("E11:E37"), "<" & 
Format(DTPicker2.Value, "dd/mm/yy"))) Then
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            s.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Else
            s.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    End If
Next s

If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Records Found")
Else
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="Technicians - Batch Record Report" & Format(Date, 
"ddmmyyyy"), _
          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Credit to @Jeeped who got me this far!

Update: Code works by reversing date formats:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim s As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
UserForm1.Hide
For Each s In Worksheets
    If CBool(Application.CountIfs(s.Range("E11:E37"), ">" & 
    Format(DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yy"), _ s.Range("E11:E37"), "<" & 
Format(DTPicker2.Value, "mm/dd/yy"))) Then
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            s.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Else
            s.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    End If
Next s

If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Records Found")
Else
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="Technicians - Batch Record Report" & Format(Date, 
"ddmmyyyy"), _
          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of objects are DTPicker 1 and 2? Have you tried using break points and examining the ,value of the pickers just after use, to confirm the expected dateserial values?

Comment: Don't check formatted dates always check the values of the dates instead. See [How Dates Work in Excel – The Calendar System Explained + Video](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/) to understand how dates are saved in Excel and how to use their value for comparison. • Instead of `Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/mm/yy"), _ s.Range("E11:E37"), "<" & 
Format(DTPicker2.Value, "dd/mm/yy"` use `DTPicker1.Value, _ s.Range("E11:E37").Value, "<" & 
DTPicker2.Value` to compare values (cells need to be formatted as date).

Comment: Tried this out but i get a type mismatch error? on `If CBool(Application.CountIfs(s.Range("E11:E37"), ">" & DTPicker1.Value, _
        s.Range("E11:E37").Value, "<" & DTPicker2.Value)) Then` i think it is because it is checking sheets all sheets some of which within the range has text rather then date formats, assume i just need to exclude these sheets from the sheet loop?

Comment: I managed to fix it by reversing my date formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the date formats and all works fine...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim s As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
UserForm1.Hide
For Each s In Worksheets
If CBool(Application.CountIfs(s.Range("E11:E37"), ">" & 
Format(DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yy"), _ s.Range("E11:E37"), "<" & 
Format(DTPicker2.Value, "mm/dd/yy"))) Then
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        s.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Else
        s.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    End If
End If
Next s

If wb Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("No Records Found")
Else
wb.SaveAs Filename:="Technicians - Batch Record Report" & Format(Date, 
"ddmmyyyy"), _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the check manually as

```
If dateValue.NumberFormat <> "mm/dd/yyyy" Then     '<-- provide the date format to validate with
```

Comment: Sorry, where in my existing code should i put this?

Comment: tried some trial and error entering into the code. please can you elaborate where i should put this?